# QGIS - Unite many lines in a single Multiline (with branches)

Tags: qgis, linestring, union, multiline

I have a shapefile that contains many lines that connect to each other, forming branches, as shown in the picture:

[image]

How can I join all these lines into a single entity? I want the attribute table to show a single line which contains all these branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the processing tool [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve)